# How do I use slices properly

Tags: python, slice

I have just learned the index and slicing in python. After I learned, I got a good idea to make. The idea briefly is that instead of writing the sequence in the code, I want the user to choose a start and an end and print the result. I have written the code and it showed no problems, but when I ran it, it didn't work :(
So I need help to make it run as I imagined.
`

```
mystring = "Omar Marouf Zaki"
print("Choose First Number")
x = input()
print("Choose Second Number")
y = input()
print(mystring[x:y])
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the Strings to Int.

`input()` return string so you need to do `print(mystring[int(x):int(y)])` to make x and y ints

Answer (score 2):

If you want cleaner code, you could convert your input to an int before assigning it to `x` and `y`, like this:

```py
x = int(input())
# ...
y = int(input())
# Now you can use [x:y] without problems becuase both x and y are integers
print(mystring[x:y])
```